# "email sent" appearing in post request responses

Tags: php, opayo

I was wondering if someone could help me figure out where this could be coming from.

Here is a successfull transaction:

> Response received: HttpResponse{body='Status=OK
>   RedirectURL=https://www.furnitureclinic.co.uk/orderSuccessful?VendorTxCode=fclinic-170720105629-212955392
>   ', statusCode=200, statusMessage='OK'}

And here a failed transaction:

> Response received: HttpResponse{body='email sentStatus=OK
>   RedirectURL=https://www.handbagclinic.co.uk/Checkout?VendorTxCode=fclinic-170720105715-107422623
>   ', statusCode=200, statusMessage='OK'}

As you can see in the failed transaction, after `body=`, it says `email sentStatus=OK` rather than just `Status=OK`.

This causing payments to Sage to fail.

I would just like to know, at which point in the payment process does this response get sent, and what could possibly be causing this to happen.

I have looked through the entire Notification URL file and no mention of "email sent" ever shows up.

Answer (score 0):

This is the last step of a Server transaction - Sage Pay will call back to you with the Notification post, which it looks like you are getting, and you respond with the 'OK' message and a redirect URL (to send the consumer's browser off to wherever).

However, if you are sending all that through, it's as if you are telling Sage Pay to reject the transaction.

I recommend setting up a simple script on your NotificationURL, which just replies (to the notification POST) with:

```
Status=OK
statusMessage=Fine
RedirectURL=<wherever>
```

And then re-introduce the complexity of signature checking etc. afterwards...